# How to change shape of fragment of circle in Kivy

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

I have circle looking like this [circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddOll.png)

and in my kv file:

```
<FragmentOfCircle>:
    size: self.size
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: (0.7, 0, 1)
        Line:
            width: self.circlewidth
            circle:
                (self.center_x, self.center_y, min(self.width, self.height),
                0,60)
```

and I have six fragments and I want to change the shape of them in place where that fragments are connected to one another.
For example sth 
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kwzW.png)

But how to change this shape

Answer (score 1):

Use the [cap](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.graphics.html#kivy.graphics.Line) attribute. Set it to `'none'`
Try something like this:

```py
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.graphics import Line, Color


class Circle(Widget):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Circle,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        segments = 12
        seg = 360/segments
        with self.canvas:
            for i in range(1,segments+1):
                Color(1.0/segments*i,1,1,mode="hsv")
                Line(circle=[200,200,100,
                             seg*i-1,
                             seg*i+seg],
                             width=15, cap="none")

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Circle()


MyApp().run()
```